# How to re-sync with Git repo from new machine

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had to replace my computer recently and I was able to copy all my website files to a new machine. My code has changes that I hadn't yet pushed to Bitbucket before my computer died. I have not yet run `git init` on my new machine so I don't have a local Git repo, only the files. What's the best way to pick up where I left off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone from the bitbucket repo, identity the revision where you were working on when the computer crashed, check it out, replace the files that were modified (that you are saying you kept, right) and move on with your life.

Comment: to check out would it be `git checkout master` or `git checkout [last commit id]` or something else?

Comment: As i said, you have to look for the revision that you were working from... on bitbucket other developers _might_ have already pushed other stuff so just checking out a branch just like that won't be close enough. Once you identify the revision that you were working from, check it out using the revision ID (perhaps creating a new branch with -b), and then replace the files that you have with you on top of it. That should be enough to be able to continue working knowing that you won't lose any of your changes and you won't unwillingly drop changes from other developers.

Comment: i'm the only developer with access to this repo, so i'm happy to check out the current state of the repo—the master branch—replace modified files and commit the changes. so after i've cloned the repo, could i do this? `git checkout master` -> replace modified files -> `git add .` -> `git commit -m "message"` -> `git push`

Comment: Sounds like you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps clone it to a different directory, and copy the `.git` folder into your new working copy.